# Copy table rows in multiple table using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I've got a litte bit problem here. I just want a deep copy of all data in my object and append it to tables based with some conditions. I tried some .clone() but it doesn't meet my expections. So here is my jQuery Code:

```js
$.post(self.baseUrl + "ReviewCountof", {CountNo: countno}, function(data) {
  var tableAll = $('#allCount tbody');
  var tableUc = $('#Uncounted tbody');
  var tableUm = $('#Unmatch tbody');
  var tableMatched = $('#Matched tbody');
  var count = data.length;
  tableAll.empty();
  tableUc.empty();
  tableUm.empty();
  tableMatched.empty();
  $.each(data, function(i, v) {
    var Desc = $('<td/>').append(v.Description);
    var expCount = $('<td/>').append(v.ExpectedCount);
    var total = $('<td/>').append(v.Total);
    var discrepancy = $('<td/>').append(v.Discrepancy);
    var cost = $('<td/>').append(v.Cost);
    var row = $('<tr/>').append(Desc).append(expCount).append(total).append(discrepancy).append(cost);

    if (v.Total == null || v.Total == '') {
      Uncounted++;
      tableUc.append(row);
    }
    if (parseFloat(v.ExpectedCount) !== parseFloat(v.Total)) {
      countUnmatched++;
      tableUm.append(row);
    } else {
      countMatched++;
      tableMatched.append(row);
    }

  });
}).success(function() {
  $('.LoadingData').hide();
});
```

I want to append all the data in `tableAll` element. So I've thought it would work like if I did like this:

```
tableAll.append(row);
```

But it didn't work.

Is there any way to achieve this with appropriate code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call:

```
var row = $('<tr/>');
tableFoo.append(row); // row created on tableFoo
tableBar.append(row); // row moved from tableFoo to tableBar
```

You are just moving the `row` around. Which means the `row` will end up in the last place you called `.append(row)`.

You have that problem in several parts of your code. To fix it, instead of appending the recently-created `row`, append a clone of it, like:

```
tableFoo.append(row.clone()); // row created on tableFoo
tableBar.append(row.clone()); // row created on tableBar
```

**Demo:**

```js
var Uncounted = 0;
var countUnmatched = 0;
var countMatched = 0;
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1h1yxz", function(data) {
  var tableAll = $('#allCount tbody');
  var tableUc = $('#Uncounted tbody');
  var tableUm = $('#Unmatch tbody');
  var tableMatched = $('#Matched tbody');
  var count = data.length;
  tableAll.empty();
  tableUc.empty();
  tableUm.empty();
  tableMatched.empty();
  $.each(data, function(i, v) {
    var Desc = $('<td/>').append(v.Description);
    var expCount = $('<td/>').append(v.ExpectedCount);
    var total = $('<td/>').append(v.Total);
    var discrepancy = $('<td/>').append(v.Discrepancy);
    var cost = $('<td/>').append(v.Cost);
    var row = $('<tr/>').append(Desc).append(expCount).append(total).append(discrepancy).append(cost);

    if (v.Total == null || v.Total == '') {
      Uncounted++;
      tableUc.append(row.clone());
    }
    if (parseFloat(v.ExpectedCount) !== parseFloat(v.Total)) {
      countUnmatched++;
      tableUm.append(row.clone());
    } else {
      countMatched++;
      tableMatched.append(row.clone());
    }
    
    tableAll.append(row.clone());

  });
});
```

```css
table, tbody, tr, td { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

allCount:
<table id="allCount">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<br>
Uncounted:
<table id="Uncounted">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<br>
Unmatch:
<table id="Unmatch">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<br>
Matched:
<table id="Matched">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! It works! I've just added your code simply as this `tableAll.append(row.clone());`. Thank you  @acdcjunior.

Comment: Hi! I just wanted to let you know you should add `row.clone()` in several places of your code (to be safe, everywhere you call `tableFoo.append()`, really). The first version of my answer only suggested the change to `tableAll`. But, again, you should do it everywhere. Read on the answer again and if you have any doubts, just ask.

Comment: Great! You helped me a lot to understand how the `append` to row works! So, i used your advise and placed `row.clone()` in all of my tables and it just worked perfectly. Again, thank you so much! @acdcjunior.